# Stereotype extending more than one Metaclass UML Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

In my EA profile model I want to extend two metaclasses (connector and information flow), how do I set the (UML::BaseUMLType) BaseUMLType in the toolbox attributes box? In case I dont use this detail, the stereotype is not usable (contrary to one stereotype extending one metaclass).
Generally speaking, I want to have a connector that merges the properties of UML::Connector and UML::InformationFlow.

Comment: Please edit this to one single question and post the other one in another question.

Comment: Why don't you explain what you are trying to achieve, and what is going wrong, with as much detail as possible. Currently it's mostly a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **'Profile Helper'**

With this tool you can simply select your stereotype to appear in the toolbox.
[image]